# Can I use GET method from inside a C Program

Tags: c, xml, linux, http, get

I'm grabbing xml data from an api which only supports GET method. Can I access this method from inside the C program?

What libraries do I need?

Is there actually a library??

Comment: what answer do you expect? "No, C supports only POST requests" ??

Comment: According to REST standards, this is a good things that indeed you don't have to use another http verb to retrieve data: GET is the verb used to read without changing the current state of the service invoked.
Regarding API I am sure some exist: I found this one for example: [http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/](http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: What answer do you need?  Is there actually a question?? ;)

Comment: You may want to check out libcurl: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/

Comment: @PaulEvans Yes, I was asking what library I should be using to grab xml from API's with GET method. xmlrpc-c is exactly that. Almost no guidance/info exists on web about this topic. Mostly people use other, rather more popular programming languages. So I needed to ask this question. I'm sorry if my question is not well shaped. I really didn't know how GET method would be implemented into a C program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need 2 libraries:

- one for fetching data, and I suggest you using [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl)
- one for parsing xml, and I suggest you [libxml](http://www.xmlsoft.org/)